# Connecting Power BI to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to connect Power BI to SharePoint to source my data and create a report. I see 3 SharePoint options under Get Data in Power BI. I am not very sure which one to use. I tried all 3 (SharePoint folder, SharePoint Online list and SharePoint list) but I end up with an error mentioned below:

[image]

The url I am using looks like:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Sharepoint Online List`.

This would prompt a message that would ask for your site, where the list is stored

[image]

The site URL structure should look like this

https://`organization name`.sharepoint.com/sites/`site name`/

After that, it would ask for your login details and finally a navigation pane with all the assets of that site including your list. In my case, `Test 2` is the list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot Angelo. I figured the solution for this sometime back and your solution works too. :) Thanks again.